# Double and triple notifications

Tags: macos, calendar

When activating Calendar app I get double and triple notifications on my appointments - for example birthdays, holidays etc. How can I get rid of these double notifications?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have local calendars and iCloud calendars.

Make sure that the events and birthdays are only in one calendar. I had the same problem before. After consolidating my calendars and moving them to iCloud it was fixed.